# Android Telephony API and CellSignalStrength

Tags: android

How to use `CellSignalStrengthLte` in **Android**? Cannot find anything on internet.

I want to call `getDBM()` function but cannot find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use  TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();   iterate over he list and then use getCellSignalStrength();